# Getting polylines back from leaflet when using esri-leaflet featureLayer

Tags: leaflet, esri-leaflet

I have a leaflet map that uses esri-leaflet to display a feature layer created for arcgis that is a number of paths. These paths are created correctly and I can see them on the map, but they aren't the visual I need. Instead I'm interested in getting the `LatLng` of the centroid of the path.

Since I know leaflet polylines have a `getCenter` method, I just need to know how to access these objects after they are drawn to the map. Is this possible?

Code for this follows:

```
let mymap = L.map("mapid").setView([lat, lng], 18);
L.esri.basemapLayer("Gray").addTo(mymap);
var subtleUA = L.esri
  .tiledMapLayer({
    url:
      "https://mymapserver.../"
  })
  .addTo(mymap);
let roomFeatures = L.esri.featureLayer({url:"https://mymapserver/../interiors/16"}).addTo(mymap)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After feature layer is loaded you can use layer's `.eachFeature` method to loop through features and get center of each feature:

```
let roomFeatures = L.esri.featureLayer({url:"https://mymapserver/../interiors/16"});

roomFeatures.on('load', function() {
  roomFeatures.eachFeature(function(layer) {
    let center = layer.getCenter();
    console.log(center);
  });
});
roomFeatures.addTo(mymap);
```

Comment: excellent! I wasn't sure if the features were actual polylines after using esri leaflet but this is great!